# Cannot get DataCollator to prepare tf dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model, huggingface

I’m trying to follow this tutorial to fine-tune bert for a NER task using my own dataset. https://www.philschmid.de/huggingface-transformers-keras-tf.  Below is my shortened code, and the error due to the last line of the code. I’m new to all these, and thank you in advance for helping out!

```
# load dataset, 
df_converters = {'tokens': ast.literal_eval, 'labels': ast.literal_eval}
train_df = pd.read_csv("train_df_pretokenization.csv", converters=df_converters)
train_df = train_df.head(10)

# model and pretrained tokenizer
model_ckpt = "indobenchmark/indobert-base-p2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_ckpt) 

# tokenization, and align labels 
def tokenize_and_align_labels(batch): 

    tag2int = {'B-POI':0, 'B-STR':1, 'E-POI':2, 'E-STR':3, 'I-POI':4,
           'I-STR':5, 'S-POI':6, 'S-STR':7, 'O':8}
           
    #tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(batch['tokens'], is_split_into_words=True, truncation = True, padding = True)
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(batch['tokens'], is_split_into_words=True, truncation = True)
    labels=[]
    for idx, label in enumerate(batch['labels']):
        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index = idx)
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids: 
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
                label_ids.append(tag2int[label[word_idx]])
            else: 
                label_ids.append(tag2int[label[word_idx]])
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
        labels.append(label_ids)
    tokenized_inputs['tags'] = labels

    return tokenized_inputs

def encode_dataset(ds):
    return ds.map(tokenize_and_align_labels, batched= True, batch_size=10, remove_columns=['labels','tokens', 'index'])
    
train_ds = Dataset.from_pandas(train_df)
train_ds_encoded = encode_dataset(train_ds)

# prepare model input 
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer, return_tensors="tf")

tf_train_dataset = train_ds_encoded.to_tf_dataset(
    columns= ['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'tags'],
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=5,
    collate_fn=data_collator
)
```

> ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched tensors with the same length.

I thought data collator is supposed to take care of the padding work given the requested batch size, and I don’t understand why feeding in sequences of different lengths will cause this error. Indeed, the tutorial runs fine without specifying padding or truncation. My code will run if I add padding = True to the tokenizer in the function (the line I commented out in the function). But I don’t think it is the right place to add paddings.

Comment: You need padding if you're going to have ragged tensors. Are the inputs the same shape?

Answer (score 0):

I think raising an error here is fine given that it is explicitly mentioning what must be done, and that truncating, as a potential loss of information, should be opt-in even when a max length and padding are defined.

```
tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(batch['tokens'], 
       is_split_into_words=True,
       return_tensors="tf",
       truncation=True,
       padding='max_length', 
       max_length=10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Yet I think padding should be added when creating mini-batches (e.g., of 16 sequences) instead of when doing batch-preprocessing using `.map`. Indeed, data collator should do the job of add padding to a batch of sequences of different lengths. I was able to get it to work by changing the column name from "tags" to "labels" (the column that stores the ID-aligned-NER tags). I believe "labels" is a special column name for the data collator.